# Alternating row color div

Tags: css

I wanted to try adding zebra stripes to my div table every 5 or so rows but I tested out the function by going with the even first if it works as expected.

I tried the `nth-child` line and `nth-of-type` line but there doesn't seem to be any change in the table. Am I doing something wrong??

This is the code portion that creates my table

```
 $.ajax({
url: "viewDayInDocuments",
type: 'post',
data: {currentDay: currentDay, currentMonth: currentMonth, currentYear: currentYear},
success: function(result){
    $('.descCell').text('');
    $('.descCell').remove();
    $('.row').remove();
    $('.failure').text('');
    $('.failure').remove();
    $('.listItem').remove();
    $('.incomingForm').remove();

    incomingDoc = JSON.parse(result);
    if(incomingDoc.details == false){
        $('.row').remove();
        $('.descCell').text('');
        $('.descCell').remove();
        $("#superWrap").hide();
        $("#noDocs").append("<div class = 'failure'>No Documents Available</div>");
        $('#noDocs').show();
    }
    else{
                $("#mainListing").prepend("<div class = 'row'><div class = 'cell'><div class = 'descCell'><p class = 'listItem'><form class = 'incomingForm' method = 'POST' action = '/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoIncoming'><b>Reference Number: </b><a href = '#' onclick = 'sendForm(this)' class = 'list'>"
                + incomingDoc.details[i].referenceNo + "</a><br/><label class = 'list'>" 
                + "<b>Sender: </b>"
                + incomingDoc.details[i].sender + "<br/>"
                + "<b>Company Name: </b>"
                + incomingDoc.details[i].companyName + "<br/>"
                + "<b>Subject: </b>"
                + incomingDoc.details[i].subject + 
                "<label><input type = 'hidden' name = 'incomingId' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].incomingId + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'referenceNo' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].referenceNo + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'documentType' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].documentTypeId + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'documentDate' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].documentDate + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'dateReceived' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].dateReceived + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'sender' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].sender + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'companyId' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].companyId + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'company' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].companyName + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'staffName' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].responsibleStaffName +
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'staff' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].responsibleStaffId + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'subject' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].subject + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'actionDone' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].actionDone + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'track' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].track + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'completed' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].completed + 
                "'/><input type = 'hidden' name = 'remarks' value = '" + incomingDoc.details[i].remarks + 
                "'/></form></div></div>");
        } 
        $("#superWrap").show();      
        //$("#myform").show();
    }

        //if link is clicked go edit the form with given values
}
```

});

My CSS related code for cell:

```
.cell{
    min-width: 450px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.cell:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
```

Rendered Code div block:

```
<div id="superWrap" style="display: block;">
    <div id="wrapper">

            <div class="listIncoming">
                <div class="desc">
                <label><b>Incoming Documents on the Day</b></label>
                </div>

                <div id="mainListing"><div class="row"><div class="cell"><div class="descCell"><p class="listItem"></p><form class="incomingForm" method="POST" action="/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoIncoming"><b>Reference Number: </b><a href="#" onclick="sendForm(this)" class="list">2014-IN05-ORD-1245</a><br><label class="list"><b>Sender: </b>Discuss<br><b>Company Name: </b>NPA<br><b>Subject: </b>List it down as subject<label><input type="hidden" name="incomingId" value="42"><input type="hidden" name="referenceNo" value="2014-IN05-ORD-1245"><input type="hidden" name="documentType" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="documentDate" value="2014-05-12"><input type="hidden" name="dateReceived" value="2014-05-12"><input type="hidden" name="sender" value="Discuss"><input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="company" value="NPA"><input type="hidden" name="staffName" value="Staff, Meeting A"><input type="hidden" name="staff" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="subject" value="List it down as subject"><input type="hidden" name="actionDone" value="no"><input type="hidden" name="track" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="completed" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="remarks" value="hey"></label></label></form></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="cell"><div class="descCell"><p class="listItem"></p><form class="incomingForm" method="POST" action="/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoIncoming"><b>Reference Number: </b><a href="#" onclick="sendForm(this)" class="list">398041839213</a><br><label class="list"><b>Sender: </b>me<br><b>Company Name: </b>NPA<br><b>Subject: </b>asdas subject<label><input type="hidden" name="incomingId" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="referenceNo" value="398041839213"><input type="hidden" name="documentType" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="documentDate" value="2014-05-12"><input type="hidden" name="dateReceived" value="2014-05-12"><input type="hidden" name="sender" value="me"><input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="company" value="NPA"><input type="hidden" name="staffName" value="Man, Alf B"><input type="hidden" name="staff" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="subject" value="asdas subject"><input type="hidden" name="actionDone" value="sad"><input type="hidden" name="track" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="completed" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="remarks" value="dsad"></label></label></form></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="cell"><div class="descCell"><p class="listItem"></p><form class="incomingForm" method="POST" action="/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoIncoming"><b>Reference Number: </b><a href="#" onclick="sendForm(this)" class="list">908941</a><br><label class="list"><b>Sender: </b>me<br><b>Company Name: </b>NPA<br><b>Subject: </b>testing<label><input type="hidden" name="incomingId" value="24"><input type="hidden" name="referenceNo" value="908941"><input type="hidden" name="documentType" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="documentDate" value="2014-05-06"><input type="hidden" name="dateReceived" value="2014-05-12"><input type="hidden" name="sender" value="me"><input type="hidden" name="companyId" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="company" value="NPA"><input type="hidden" name="staffName" value="Staff, Meeting A"><input type="hidden" name="staff" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="subject" value="testing"><input type="hidden" name="actionDone" value="round round"><input type="hidden" name="track" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="completed" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="remarks" value="round"></label></label></form></div></div></div>
                    <input type="button" value="Close" id="btnOK" align="center">
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code originally in the question has no 2nd, 4th etc. child of anything. Now it has some code that generates markup. Show an example of an actual HTML document (such as a minimal case generated by your code) that you are trying to solve. Also consider using a real table if you are trying to present tabular data, as it seems.

Comment: Adding an image doesn't help here. We need to see the final html!

Comment: what do you mean by final html?? Sorry it's my first time hearing that term

Comment: do you mean the code found when you inspect element??

Comment: I meant the actual html which is rendered on the page... and yes  the code found when you inspect an element gives you this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current markup this is what you need:

```
.row{
    min-width: 450px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.row:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZY67T/)**

Comment: I assumed it was cell since when I did an onhover change on background...it worked properly. Also tried your code and no changes happened when I tried...should I post the full code for table and not just sample code??

Comment: yes post the full code - also, check out the fiddle I posted to see the kind of markup this solution uses

Comment: It would be better if you include the final html - after the page is loaded

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yWQnM/) using your updated code - it seems to work fine

Comment: weird...there must be a mistake my side then...I can't seem to get it running here when I try. But since it seems to work your side I'm guessing this is indeed the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
.cell:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
```

should be

```
.descCell:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
```

`nth-child` doesn't select the class's children, it treats the class as the child to a parent element.

Comment: I tried doing this but nothing seems to have happened

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the rows dynamically, then set the class name (e.g., toggling between `"cell-0"` and `"cell-1"`) according to the `ith` row you are generating. The 0 or 1 in the class name will just be `i%2` since you are alternating between 2 colors here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating rows dynamically, then you must declare the `nth-child` selector to `.row`. So it must be like this:

```
.row{
    min-width: 450px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-top: 1px solid;
}
.row:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #B0C4DE;
}
```